# Image in ImageView is stretched - Android

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I am trying to make a small image appear on my screen.  I want it to be a small square.  With the below code, it shows up as a long flat rectangle.  I have attached a picture of what it looks like below.

**java code**

```
ImageView q1Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q1Image);
q1Image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

**xml code**

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/q1Image"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

[image: test]

**EDIT**
If I make the width and height equal to `50dp` each, the image gets bigger but is still a flat looking rectangle.

Comment: Please post a layout with parents of your TableRow.

Comment: https://themillibit.wordpress.com/2017/09/25/why-are-my-bitmaps-all-stretched/ Here's a blog post I wrote to answer this exact question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FIT_XY will stretch your image to fit all yout ImageView.
Use scale type fitCenter to preserve aspect ratio by placing the image in center if your ImageView

```
q1Image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html
For other options.

Comment: Same flat rectangle still appears after switching to ````FIT_CENTER````.

Comment: Seems like the TableLayout is stretching a column with ImageView. Try to add andorid:shrinkColumns="0" and android:stretchColumns="1" to your TableLayout.

Comment: Works!  I added what you suggested to the ````TableLayout```` and also took out the layout_weight from the ````ImageView````.  Thank you Doc!

Comment: In xml, android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Answer (score 17):

Your scaling the Image wrong. Here are all scaletypes:

[image]

Top row (l-r) center, centerCrop, centerInside.

Bottom row (l-r): fitCenter, fitStart, fitEnd, fitXY.

You probably need `fitCenter`:

```
q1Image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Comment: I tried ````q1Image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);```` and also tried just ````CENTER```` as @ben75 suggested.  All still give me the same result as what I posted initially.

Answer (score 1):

Without the full layout XML this is just speculation, but seeing as you don't appear to have fixed the problem by changing the scale type, here are some other suggestions:

1. Wouldn't it be better if the `layout_weight` of the `ImageView` was zero?
2. Are you specifying `android:stretchColumns` on the `TableLayout`?
3. The image looks like it is being stretched to match the width of the text below.  How many columns have you got in your table?  It looks like the text in the other rows is in column 0 (as is the image in your first row) and the text in the first row is in column 1. If you want to leave column zero blank for the other rows, you need to specify `android:layout_column` on the text views.

Comment: Column 1 is supposed be all images.  The table has 4 columns.  Right now, except for row 1, all the lowercase i's in column 0 are place holders.  The layout_weight is set to .1 because I only want column 0 to account to 10% of the row space (which the place holders correctly show).  I am specifying ````android:stretchColumns="*"````.

Comment: The dimensions of the picture is 100x100.  Not sure if that matters.