# Image View doesn't show clear image defined in xml

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

In my code I want to set a default image for my imageview. All my images are of 174px X 174px. So, I want the default image to be same size. This is my xml for image view

```
//....code

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivCover"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="Default Image"
    android:src="@drawable/default_cover" />


//....some other code
```

Now, my default_cover.jpg is also 174px X 174px. But it shows a smaller image. I've tried all

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:scaleType="center"
android:scaleType="matrix"
```

even when most of them were senseless for me but still I tried all of 'em & none of them works. Then I specified the height & width of image by specifying

```
android:layout_width="174px"
android:layout_height="174px"
```

(I know using dp is better than px but because this image size is fixed & I was just testing it). So it shows

[image: default image which doesn't look good][default image]

while when loaded from an external url using

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url_source_for_image).getContent());
ivCover.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

desired image

[image: clear image with desired image quality][]

The two pictures may not look very different here but the difference is very clear on my android device. And please don't say that I didn't try other solutions..
Here is a list of links of so itself..

[ImageView fit without stretching the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925530/imageview-fit-without-stretching-the-image)

[Fit image into ImageView, keep aspect ratio and then resize ImageView to image dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d)

[ImageView one dimension to fit free space and second evaluate to keep aspect ration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202000/imageview-one-dimension-to-fit-free-space-and-second-evaluate-to-keep-aspect-rat)

[Resizing ImageView to fit to aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400113/resizing-imageview-to-fit-to-aspect-ratio)

[Maximum width and height for ImageView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270394/maximum-width-and-height-for-imageview-in-android)

[Image in ImageView is stretched - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285007/image-in-imageview-is-stretched-android)

[Android: How to prevent image from being scaled in ImageView or ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406172/android-how-to-prevent-image-from-being-scaled-in-imageview-or-imagebutton)

Comment: Which drawable folder is your bitmap in?  If you put a 50x50 bitmap in drawable-ldpi and a 174x174 bitmap in drawable-hdpi, Android will decide which one to display based on the resolution of the device, not on the size you specified.  If you want show a specific bitmap to be used on all devices, regardless of resolution, put it in res\drawable-nodpi.

Comment: Images are in res\drawable-xxhdpi because I think android smartly down scales the image size to show in low resolution devices.

Comment: Right, so maybe it's scaling the image down to lower resolution, and then scaling it back up to fit your specified size.  Does it work if you put it in drawable-nodpi instead?

Comment: If I set height & width to wrap_content then it just shows a smaller image & when I specify those attributes = 174px then it again shows those distorted pixels.

Comment: Oh yes! It worked. Actually I had copied that image previously. This time.. I moved it & it works fine now. I wonder that I never came across this no-dpi thing before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted. If you want then please add it as an answer. :)

Comment: No worries, glad to help.  I think no-dpi is not that popular, so you don't see it mentioned that often.  Sure saved me a lot of headaches when I found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the answer is to use drawable-nodpi.  For future reference, if you have the same named image in both the ldpi/hdpi/etc and in no-dpi, I think the no-dpi one will be ignored.